# XmlReader does not read file if it contains a self closing tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5, xmlreader

i have the following Xml structure:

```
<event id="0" start_time="2014-05-21 10:00:00" duration="86340">

  <short_event_descriptor lang="alb" name="Programet e Kanalit A1">Programe/Emisione</short_event_descriptor>

  <extended_event_descriptor lang="alb">

    <text>Programet dhe Emisionet e perditshme te kanalit A1</text>

  </extended_event_descriptor>

</event>

<event id="1" start_time="2014-05-22 10:00:00" duration="86340">

  <short_event_descriptor lang="alb" name="Programs of Channel A1">Programs/TalkShows</short_event_descriptor>

  <extended_event_descriptor lang="alb">

    <text />

  </extended_event_descriptor>

</event>
```

and the code i am trying is the following:

```
try
            {

                while (reader.Read())
                {

                        switch (reader.NodeType)
                        {
                            case XmlNodeType.Element: // The node is an element.
                                if (reader.Name == "channel")
                                {
                                    while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute())
                                    {
                                        if (reader.Name == "name")
                                        {
                                           // epg = new epg2();
                                            epg.channelname = reader.Value;
                                            epg.number = Convert.ToInt32(channelNames[i][1]);
                                            xmlfile.Add(epg);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                if (reader.Name == "event")
                                {
                                    while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute())
                                    {
                                        if (reader.Name == "start_time")
                                        {
                                           // Ev = new Event();
                                            Ev.starttime = Convert.ToDateTime(reader.Value);
                                        }
                                        else if (reader.Name == "duration")
                                        {
                                            Ev.duration = Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value);
                                        }
                                        else if (reader.Name == "name")
                                        {
                                            Ev.duration = Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                if (reader.Name == "short_event_descriptor")
                                {
                                    while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute())
                                    {
                                        if (reader.Name == "name")
                                        {
                                            Ev.name = reader.Value;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                break;
                            case XmlNodeType.Text: //Display the text in each element.
                                if (shenjuar > 0)
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        Ev.shortDescription = reader.Value.Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace("Sub. Ang", "").Replace("Sub. Alb", "").Replace('\"', '\''); ;
                                    }
                                    catch
                                    {
                                        Ev.shortDescription = reader.Value;
                                    }
                                    shenjuar *= -1;
                                }
                                else if (shenjuar < 0)
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        Ev.longDescription = reader.Value.Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace("Sub. Ang", "").Replace("Sub. Alb", "").Replace('\"', '\''); ;
                                    }
                                    catch
                                    {
                                        Ev.longDescription = reader.Value;
                                    }
                                    shenjuar *= -1;
                                    epg.EventNumber.Add(Ev);
                                }
                                else reader.Skip();
                                break;
                            case XmlNodeType.EndElement: //Display the end of the element
                                reader.Skip();
                                break;

                        }
                    }
                    xmlfile.Add(epg);
                }

            catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe)
            {
                TextBox1.Text = "Error. Can not find " + CName + ".xml file";
                //return;
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                TextBox1.Text = "Unknown Error: \r\nError on " + CName + ".xml file \r\n Error Description:" + exc.Message;
                //return;
            }
        }
```

the point is that this piece of code is used for a list of XML files, and the problem is that for some files the  tag is self-closing, and in this case the reader skips them from reading at all. Since the XML files are brought to the company as standard and change their content every day, i can not change their structure. I have tried to use  the IsEmptyElement property, i have tried different ways to read the data, but no matter what, it always skips the files with the empty  tag. is been a week now that i am trying every single tutorial i could find, but no handling has worked

Answer (score 0):

You have code which skips your `text` element:

```
if (reader.IsStartElement("text"))
    reader.Skip();
```

Remove it and check self-closing elements with `XmlReader.IsEmptyElement`.

Comment: the piece of code you see, is the "last version". before it, i have tried without the reader.Skip property, and i checked for the  text element if it is empty, but this didn't work either